# Django CURL conversion with JS auto-redirection

Tags: python, django, curl

I have the following code in PHP:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $fields = array(
        "cart_id" => 1,
        "value"   => 1,
        "subgw"   => 1
    );
    $fields_string = "";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "url_to_curl");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    @curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

What is the simplest way to do the same mechanic with Django/Python?
The most important part is I guess the follow location which is handled by JavaScript, and not just a 300 redirect.

Comment: Use `requests` package which has `allow_redirects` which does what you need. Docs here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/

Comment: Just tried that, but the site I'm posting to uses JS to redirect the page, so it's not working :( still looking for a solution though.

Comment: Hmm. You then have to execute the JS locally or use Selenium or PhantomJS to evaluate the entire page. Hope that helps.